# Auto fill and submit form via URL & post method

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm currently trying to submit a form via the URL of the site.

the form I'm currently using:

```
<form action="index.php?doc=login" method="post" name="f">

    User: <input type="text" value="" name="nick" /><br />
    Pass: <input type="password" value="" name="pwd" /><br />

    Stay Logged In: <input type="checkbox" name="persistent"/><br />
    Invisible <input type="checkbox" name="invisible"/><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/>

</form>
```

so, when passing the following url:

```
http://localhost/index.php?doc=login&nick=username&pwd=secret&login=Login
```

I should be able to pass those values to the form. When entering the url into the browser and hitting enter the input fields are filled with the correct values. But the form doesn't pass the values to the doc=login.

Comment: your description doesn't entirely make sense. You submit the form, and it generates the URL you mentioned? Or you're trying to pre-fill the form with the values from the querystring? Maybe show the related PHP code for this.

Comment: @ADyson, sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to pre-fill the form (which works perfectly fine) - I'm looking to submit the form via url. so in the example above my nickname is "username" and the password is "secret". After hitting enter on the url the input fields are filled but not submitted, once I click on the Login button I'm logged in. so basically I'm asking if there is a way to auto-login to the site for known user credentials.

Comment: Is this your site, or someone else's? If it's yours, you could write some script on the page which, after the page had loaded, would validate the form fields and, if they're all filled in, automatically submit the form.

Comment: @Adyson, no, it's not my own site. I'd like to log into the site every hour , check the difference on the website and get a notification whenever it's updated.

Comment: the reason you can't log into the site using the URL by typing it into the browser is because doing that causes a GET request. But as you can see from the form's "method" attribute, actually logging in requires a POST request. When you do a GET request, the server ignores what you did and just populates the form fields, it doesn't initiate the actual login process because it's the wrong kind of request. You might be able to do what you want using some kind of automated testing framework. There are lots around for free online.